# LLamar a una función almacenada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de llamar a una función almacenada desde `PHP`,estoy seguro que estoy teniendo algún error de sintaxis en la forma en la que invoco al procedimiento almacenado,a continuación les adjunto el código.

**Código PHP**

```
<?php 
$paisSelecionado=$_POST['paisSelecionado'];
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT fDeportistaPais(:param_pais)");
$sentencia->bindParam(':param_pais', $paisSelecionado);
$sentencia->execute();
$sentencia=$connection->query('@numeroDeDeportistas as 
numeroDeDeportistas');
$res=$sentencia->fetchAll();
?>
```

Función almacenada de la base de datos

```
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS fDeportistaPais(param_pais varchar(30))                 
returns int 
DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN  
DECLARE numeroDeDeportistas int;
SELECT COUNT(deportistas.codDeportista) INTO numeroDeDeportistas
FROM
deportistas
INNER JOIN paises ON deportistas.paisDeportista = paises.codPais
WHERE paises.nombrePais LIKE param_pais;
return  numeroDeDeportistas;
END
/
```

El procedimiento devuelve el numero de deportistas según un país que le 
pasamos por parámetro,lo eh probado en el `PHPMyadmin` y devuelve bien el 
resultado,estoy seguro de que es un problema de sintaxis desde `PHP`.

Comment: Primero prueba como se tiene que ejecutar desde le gestor de base de datos, y cuando ya tengas como se ejecuta simplemente tienes que ejecutar la consulta con `PHP`, en lo personal primero pruebo que funcione bien en el gestor de base de datos y luego ya lo ejecuto desde el lenguaje de programación

Comment: Lo he hecho y me esta devolviendo los valores esperados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de ejecutar la sentencia , podría obtener los valores haciendo uso de [fetchcolumn()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php). **No hace falta ejecutar otra query**

Otra observación es que si emplea el operador `LIKE` quizá parte de la condición debería ser `WHERE paises.nombre LIKE CONCAT('%',param_pais,'%');`.

**PHP**

```
<?php
  $paisSelecionado=$_POST['paisSelecionado'];
  $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT fDeportistaPais(:param_pais)");
  $sentencia->bindParam(':param_pais', $paisSelecionado);
  $sentencia->execute();
  echo $sentencia->fetchColumn();
?>
```

Comment: vale acabo de hacer la modificación que comentas,solo haciendo la consulta una vez,pero me dice lo siguiente:Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined en la linea 29

Comment: Ese error es cuando se le pasa los parámetros erróneos a `execute` , por tanto debería verificar los nombres y el total de parámetros de la función. o si `param_pais` es igual en `prepare` que en el `binding`

Comment: Si lo que me extraña es que como vez solo recibe el nombre de el país,y también he tenido cuidado nombrándolo igual que en la función almacenada  `param_pais`,a todas estas lo he probado en el **PHPMyAdmin**y efectivamente me devuelve los valores esperados. también le hago un echo a la variable `$paisSelecionado` y me recoge bien el valor de el comboBox de donde lo estoy seleccionando.

Comment: Simulé su problema en mi servidor local y funciona correctamente. Lo cuál me parece muy raro que le muestre algún error.

Comment: Después de un rato de lucha ya lo conseguí sacar adelante,al final he tenido que sacar la lógica de el `PHP` fuera a otro archivo aparte,y cambiar alguna referencia,aparte no conocía el método `fetchColumn()` que devuelve el entero directamente,muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.